# UINavigationController / reloading views / working with views!

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view based project working with a UINavigationController.

The RootViewController performs operations for writing to a data model when a new entry is made.

I have an add (+) button on my main screen that adds an entry with a timestamp and records this to the data model.

I want to click the add button, browse a list of assets, and record an entry that includes an asset URL so I can play the asset.

I hit the add button, I then launch a new XIB as such:

```
pickerViewController = [[MyPickerViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"MyPickerViewController" bundle:nil];

//---set the property of the second view with the DatePicker view in the                current          view---
pickerViewController.myURL = importVideoURL;
```

THEN, once I have grabbed the associated asset URL that I would like to store with my entry, I remove the view from the superview to get back to my main view using:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]
```

My Problem: I can in no way, find any notification or method like viewDidAppear etc that allows me to continue execution back inside my rootViewController where I can write the Entry.

What am I missing?

HALP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to read Apple's [navigation controller documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) and work through pushing and popping view controllers. When you pop the picker view controller off the stack, you can then call `-viewDidAppear:` in the root view controller to proceed with data model updates.

Comment: I'll review this and flag once I can confirm although it sounds like the correct path, thanks.